# Big parallax with left and right eyes

Tags: google-cardboard, virtual-reality

When I use cardboard on a device which has a big screen, 5.5 inch.
And it's resolution is 2560*1440，dpi=640.
The question is that the parallax is too big, so that I can see two non overlapping images through a VR device.
So, what should I to to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Adjust the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your phone might be reporting an incorrect DPI, which prevents the SDK from drawing the two images at the right place on the screen.
According to the numbers you gave, the phone DPI should be around 534, not 640.

What is your phone model? Even better, could you give us the output of the following:

`adb shell getprop | grep "model|manufacturer|hardware|product.name|lcd_density"`

This way we could add a DPI override in the cardboard SDK for your phone model.

Comment: I have the same problem. Phone model: Meizu M2 Note.   
OS reports 480 dpi, but actual value is 403.

Comment: I used my owndevice, so I can change this value. But I think it's not good to rely on dpi for time difference.

Comment: @dcoz, here is my adb shell getprop output: `[ro.meizu.product.model]: [M5710]
[ro.product.model]: [m2 note]
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [Meizu]
[ro.boot.hardware]: [mt6735]
[ro.hardware]: [mt6735]
[ro.meizu.hardware.battery]: [ATL battery]
[ro.meizu.hardware.emmc]: [R821MB]
[ro.meizu.hardware.psn]: [81116E5BFACD]
[ro.meizu.hardware.version]: [0x57101002]
[ro.product.name]: [m2 note]
[ro.sf.lcd_density]: [480]`